# How to get an absolute URL of webapp from ExternalContext?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to retrieve the root URL of a web application from [ExternalContext](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html), but can't understand which method to use...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get `ExternalContext` from `FacesContext` and extract `request` from External context then

```
String file = request.getRequestURI();
if (request.getQueryString() != null) {
   file += '?' + request.getQueryString();
}
URL reconstructedURL = new URL(request.getScheme(),
                               request.getServerName(),
                               request.getServerPort(),
                               file);
reconstructedURL.toString();
```

[source](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=35175)

Answer (score 18):

A more concise way is:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
String baseURL = url.substring(0, url.length() - request.getRequestURI().length()) + request.getContextPath() + "/";
```

Then you don't need to fiddle with omitting the ports when the scheme is `http` and port is `80` and so on.

Answer (score 7):

This is the easiest way I've found that doesn't involve mysterious string manipulation on the various parts of the URL. It seems to work in all cases, including different protocols and ports.

```
String getAbsoluteApplicationUrl() throws URISyntaxException {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
        URI uri = new URI(request.getRequestURL().toString());
        newUri = new URI(uri.getScheme(), null,
                uri.getHost(),
                uri.getPort(),
                request.getContextPath().toString(),null, null);
        return newUri.toString();
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have one similar to BalusC's:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
String requestURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
String url = requestURL.substring(0, requestURL.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me re-phrase Jigar's answer a bit:

```
final ExternalContext ectx = context.getExternalContext();
String url = ectx.getRequestScheme()
  + "://" + ectx.getRequestServerName()
  + ":" + ectx.getRequestServerPort()
  + "/" + ectx.getRequestContextPath();
```